# JS module pattern keeps values

Tags: javascript

I created a module which analyzes a string. It counts e.g. the occurences of the letter `o` in a string:

```
export default (function () {
    var analysis = {
        occurencesOfO: 0,
    };

    var util = {
        countOs: function(input) {
            for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                analysis.occurencesOfO += input[i] === 'o' ? 1 : 0;
            }
        },
    }

    return {
        analyze: function (input) {
            util.countOs(input);
            return analysis.occurencesOfO;
        }
    };

})();
```

I use it like this:

```
import Analysis from './Analysis';

//...

let s = 'foobar';
let result = Analysis.analyze(s);
console.log('should yield: 2 but yields: ' + result);
// should yield: 2 but yields: 2

s = 'foo bar';
result = Analysis.analyze('fooo bar');
console.log('should yield: 3 but yields: ' + result);
// should yield: 3 but yields: 5

s = 'foo bar foobar';
result = Analysis.analyze('foo bar foobar');
console.log('should yield: 4 but yields: ' + result);
// should yield: 4 but yields: 9
```

I would have expected that `analysis` gets reset, but it doesn't. Why? And how do I change that?

Comment: You're mutating `foo.bar` with each call of your function, it seems logical to me that it would do such a thing. Can you precise your use case ?

Comment: Please see the amended question.

Comment: So it's ok that it counts up, however, you want a way to prevent counting up if you're entering an already analyzed string, if I understand correctly. Could you keep an array inside of your module containing the previous inputs so it won't sum if the input has already been seen?

Comment: A) don't use the module pattern if you don't want a singleton with shared state B) don't put `var foo = { bar: 0, };` in the module scope if you meant to create a new one for each `analyze` call

Comment: I re-phrased the question to make it more clear, hopefully. But basically Bergi got how I meant it. I don't want a shared state between function calls. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing this behavior because, whether intentionally or not, you are using a subtle but important JavaScript feature called [function closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). A closure is a function that references variables outside of its own internal scope. Those variables are automatically bundled into the function, but they aren't instantiated new each time the function is called. If something outside of the function modifies the closured variables, those changes will be reflected the next time the function runs.

That's all very abstract, but it's at the heart of what's going on in your example. In your `analyze` function:

```js
analyze: function (input) {
    util.countOs(input);
    return analysis.occurencesOfO;
}
```

You refer to the variable `analysis`. However, this variable is not local to the function itself! Instead, it comes from the broader context of the module. This means that when `analyze` returns, `analysis` isn't garbage collected, and neither does it lose its new value. That value is persisted until the next time you run the function.

To prevent this, the approach I would take is to make `analysis` a variable scoped within the `analyze` function:

```js
export default (function () {
    var util = {
        countOs: function(input) {
            var analysis = {
                occurencesOfO: 0
            };

            for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
                analysis.occurencesOfO += input[i] === 'o' ? 1 : 0;
            }

            return analysis;
        },
    }

    return {
        analyze: function (input) {
            var analysis =  util.countOs(input);
            return analysis.occurencesOfO;
        }
    };

})();
```

Comment: This throws the error, that `analysis` is not defined.

Comment: Ah, good point, `countOs` needs a way to reference `analysis`. I'll make an edit.

Comment: @Kurztipp How does my answer look now?